# Is there any scientific basis for this claim about thermodynamics in Scientific American?

Tags: thermodynamics

In [an article in Scientific American on different heating systems for homes](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/underloor-radiant-heating/), I came across (what seemed to me to be) a *very* odd claim:

> while radiant heat is definitely more efficient in smaller, snug homes with lower roofs, it might not always be the greenest solution in homes with bigger rooms: “In some scenarios it can be less energy efficient than forced-air heating.”

If anything, I would expect the benefits of radiant heat coming from the floor to be *much greater* in a large room with a high ceiling, since there is no need to fill the entire room with hot air, starting from the top and working your way down until you reach the people on the floor and make them warm too.

This claim seems specious (the site publishing it notwithstanding).  Is there any scientific basis for such a claim?

Comment: My limited experience is that radiant heat systems are usually installed in the ceiling rather than the floor.

Comment: @LewisMiller: I've *never* heard of them installed in the ceiling—almost always the floor, but occasionally the wall, since the floor poses a few difficulties (even if it gives a more ideal result).  Perhaps in some cases it is installed between two stories of a house, to try to heat both with one system?